# StaleElementException - Element is present in DOM

Tags: java, selenium

I am having some issues with an element, Selenium throws the StaleElementException as if the element is not attached to the DOM however I can physically see the ID that it is using to locate the element is present. The Webpage uses DevExpress grids (To my frustration) every time a button is selected the page saves and the DevExpress grid refreshes. I give selenium enough time to wait for the grid to refresh after the click, however regardless of how long I wait, the element is still detached from the DOM according to Selenium, however when I put it in to debug at the point of failure, I can see that the element is present. I have tried reinitialising the element to ensure that the element is correct. however it is still failing.  Here it the current method that I am using as a PoC:

```
    private void selectCheckBoxSystemLevel(WebElement element, String checkValue, String initialiseName) {
    try {
        waitForElementDisplay(10, element, "Checkbox is not displayed"); //awaitility method
        LOG.info("Check value " + element.getAttribute("aria-checked"));
        int count = 0;
        do {
            actions.moveToElement(element)
                    .click()
                    .build()
                    .perform();
            waitForPageLoad();
            commonMethods.handleLoadings(systemAccessLoading, 10); // method to wait for loading
            count++;
            LOG.info("Click count " + count);
            initialiseElementOnPage(initialiseName); // try reinitialise element
        } while (count <= 25 && !element.getAttribute("aria-checked").equals(checkValue));
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        LOG.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    waitForAttributeEqualText(15, element, "aria-checked", checkValue, "Checkbox value is not: " + checkValue); //awaitility method
}
```

Comment: Element might be stale even if there is an element that matches the locator. "Stale" means that you have `WebElement` object that used to reference an element in the DOM and that element was removed. Later another element can be added that could look exactly as the old one but that would be different element anyway so your reference would remain stale.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I think I have found a resolution, after your comment I did quite a lot of monitoring around how DevExpress handles the button click and you are correct, the absolute path slightly changed, I handled it by storing the ID of the element passed into this method, After the click action, I then re-initialised the WebElement by passing the ID string that I stored at the start of the method. It was then able to find the element and return the attribute. 

Thank you